# Extracting URLs from website using Pyquery and requests

Tags: python, python-requests, pyquery

I have this code:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import requests

url = "https://www.mba.org/news-and-research/forecasts-and-commentary"
content = requests.get(url).content
doc = pq(content)

Latest_Report_MO = doc("#ContentPlaceholder_C012_Col01")

print(Latest_Report_MO)
```

I get this result:

```
<div id="ContentPlaceholder_C012_Col01" class="sf_colsIn grid__unit grid__unit--1-3-l" data-sf-element="Column 2" data-placeholder-label="Column 2">&#13; <div>&#13;
    <div class="sfContentBlock sf-Long-text"><a target="_blank" href="/docs/default-source/research-and-forecasts/historical-mortgage-origination-estimates.xlsx?sfvrsn=8c6933cb_5"/><a style="margin-bottom:20px;" href="/docs/default-source/research-and-forecasts/forecasts/2023/historical-mortgage-origination-estimates.xlsx?sfvrsn=a7595901_1"/><a href="/docs/default-source/research-and-forecasts/historical-mortgage-origination-estimates.xlsx?sfvrsn=8c6933cb_5"/><a href="/docs/default-source/research-and-forecasts/historical-mortgage-origination-estimates.xlsx?sfvrsn=8c6933cb_5"/><a href="/docs/default-source/research-and-forecasts/historical-mortgage-origination-estimates.xlsx?sfvrsn=8c6933cb_5"><img src="/images/default-source/research/20125-research-forecast-web-button-qoe.png?sfvrsn=e73fc287_0" alt="" sf-size="66661"/></a> <p>Historical record of single-family, one- to four-unit loan origination estimates. Last updated June 2023. </p></div>    &#13; </div>
    </div>
```

I am interested in the `href="/docs/default-source/research-and-forecasts/historical-mortgage-origination-estimates.xlsx?sfvrsn=8c6933cb_5"`

How do I use the `.attr()` to extract this URL? Or is there any other method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can go with `doc("#ContentPlaceholder_C012_Col01 .sfContentBlock a[target='_blank']")`

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
import requests

url = "https://www.mba.org/news-and-research/forecasts-and-commentary"
content = requests.get(url).content
doc = pq(content)

items = doc("#ContentPlaceholder_C012_Col01 .sfContentBlock a[target='_blank']")
print(pq(items[0]).attr('href'))
```

Comment: I used gadget selector on the browser to select the element. How did you decide '.sfContentBlock a[target='_blank'' also needs to be added?

Comment: Due to you want to get the `<a>` tag which is being child div of `sfContentBlock` also within the parent `ContentPlaceholder_C012_Col01`, you need to go one by one child to extract it.